# How to make laravel a composer dependency for my project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

My project is a Laravel implementation. I have created a composer.json file as follows:

```
{
    "name": "company/project",
    "description": "My cool project.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "laravel/laravel": "8.*"
    }
}
```

I can put this file in its own directory and run `composer install`. This installs version 8 of `laravel/laravel` and all dependencies in the `vendor/` directory. But this is not a valid Laravel installation. If I then move the contents of `vendor/laravel/laravel` up into the main directory, copy `.env.example` to `.env` and run `composer -o dump-autoload`, then I have a directory structure that looks (as far as I can tell), just like a standard Laravel installation.

However, when I try to access the site from by browser, I get a 500 Server Error, with no apparent entries in the Apache or Laravel logs.

I know this is not an Apache configuration error because I can create exactly the same site using the command `composer create-project laravel/laravel:8.* {directory}`, and I get a function basic Laravel site.

My ultimate goal is to use composer to install my project AND Laravel, with all of it's dependencies, and get a functioning site. I am particularly interested in being able to lock all of the dependencies (including the specific version of `laravel/laravel`) via the `composer.lock` file, which will then be included with the version-controlled source of my project.

You may ask why I don't just use the recommended command to create a clean Laravel installation and just version-control the resultant composer.lock file. The reason is:  That file does not contain the specific version of `laravel/laravel`. So when I then user the `composer.json/lock` files in a clean directory, the core `laravel/larvel` files are missing.

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? Or is there a simpler way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Run `composer create-project ...` and then edit the resulting `composer.json` (either manually or via `composer require ...`) to customize for your additional needs. You should never be manually copying/moving directories around.

Comment: `laravel/laravel` isn't a dependency of a project, it is the skeleton project that gives you a shell setup to use the framework aka a laravel application ... the framework and other packages are the dependencies

Comment: Alex Howansky and lagbox. My problem is: How do I fix the version of `laravel/laravel` if it is not listed anywhere in the base `composer.json` file?

Comment: For example...  The `bootstrap/` directory and the `artisan` command are provided by `laravel/laravel`. These change from version to version. I need to make sure that I am using the same version of these files as I used to test my project.

Comment: `laravel/laravel` is the skeleton project ... that is what you use to build your application, everything that gets created when you run `composer create-project laravel/laravel ...` is your project (hence `create-project`), there is no link to `laravel/laravel` after that point (it is not a dependency of anything, ever) ... the `composer.json` file will lock the version of the dependencies, such as the framework

Comment: I get that.  So how do I lock the version of the `laravel/laravel` installer?

Comment: "I get a 500 Server Error" - please share more details about that. There must be an error log anywhere that tells you what exactly caused that error

Comment: Yes. That was my expectation as well. But I have searched all the usual places (/var/log/apache2, /var/adm/, storage/logs, etc.) and have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `composer.json` only requires `"laravel/laravel": "8.*"`, but Laravel needs a lot more to function properly. When I do a `composer create-project laravel/laravel` it generates a `composer.json` with the following:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Now this does a lot more than just requiring a vendor-folder, these contain the namespace-declarations, scripts, and the requirements for a few more things.
And also note that this requires `laravel/framework` instead of `laravel/laravel`.

All in all I suggest using the full list from here and keep stripping until it breaks if you want to.

And on the subject of version pinning, you could either put the `composer.lock`-file in your VCS and only run `composer install` (that does not update if there is lock-file).
You could also remove the `^` from all the versions that you don't want to update, that way you can restrict a version with some room for updates if you want. `8.0.1` would keep at `8.0.1`, but you could allow patches by specifying `8.0.*` as a version-requirement.

Comment: Yes. I've been through all of this already. The problem is that the root package for Laravel is `laravel/laravel`. In turn `laravel/laravel` requires all of the packages you list above. So my project only has to require `laravel/laravel` in it's `composer.json` file, and composer resolves all of the subsequent dependencies. I have also been through all of the scripts in Laravel's composer.json file and run them (either manually, or via `dump-autoload`. In short, thank you for your response, but it has not added to my existing understanding of the problem/solution.

Comment: But if you are requiring laravel as a dependency, you're basically installing laravel in your vendor-folder? I can't see that working, but maybe I'm wrong, never tried that.

Comment: L00_Cypher3r: Yes. That is what happens, but I can then move the contents of `vendor/laravel/laravel` into the top-level directory, and everything looks to be right.  But the Apache server reports a 500 error when I try to use the resultant directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I gave up trying to make this work. Instead, I now follow these steps to install a new site:

```
composer create-project --no-install --no-scripts laravel/laravel:{version} {SITE}
cd {SITE}
svn export --force {repo}/composer.json .
svn export --force {repo}/composer.lock .
composer install
svn co {repo} .
svn -R revert .
```

This allows me to create a site with the specific version of Laravel that I need.